# Send email with Inbound rule

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

i am new to alfresco share and i want to perform an action when users add a document. The action is to send email to all site members with the link of added document.

I know that there is something called email template, any ideas how to write such a template from inbound rules?

Informations: Alfresco Version: 4.2 community

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done by setting up a rule. First, see the doc about how to set up a rule on a folder:
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/library-folder-rules-define-create.html

As part of that, you'll specify the "Send an email" action. When you select that action you will also select an email template to use from a list of out-of-the-box email templates.

If you want to change the template or add a new one, you'll find them in the Data Dictionary under "Email Templates" and then "Notify Email Templates".